# AngularJS Data Binding controllers

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I'm working on a spring boot application with angular js and have hit a wall. 
I have the bones of the starter app complete, but I am having trouble with the controller js file. I get a white blank screen when I run the spring boot app. where am i going wrong, and also is there a cleaner or more efficient way of coding the controllers? How would I go about adding different controllers, the same way as I have been doing?

```
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).controller('shipwreckListController', function($scope, $state, popupService, $window, Shipwreck) {
    $scope.shipwrecks = Shipwreck.query(); // Fetch all shipwrecks, - issues a GET to api/vi/shipwrecks
    $scope.deleteShipwreck = function(shipwreck) {
        if(popupService.showPopup('Really delete this?')){
            shipwreck.$delete(function(){
                $scope.shipwrecks = Shipwreck.query();
                $state.go('shipwrecks');
            });
        }
    };
}).controller('shipwreckViewController', function($scope, $stateParams, Shipwreck){
    $scope.shipwreck = Shipwreck.get({id: $stateParams.id}); // get a single shipwreck. Issue a GET to /api/v1/shipwrecks/:id
}).controller('shipwreckCreateController', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, Shipwreck){
    $scope.shipwreck = new Shipwreck(); // create new shipwreck instance, properties will be set via ng-model on UI
    $scope.addShipwreck = function() {
        $scope.shipwreck.$save(function() {
            $state.go('shipwrecks'); // on success go back to the list
        });
    };
}).controller('shipwreckEditController', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, Shipwreck){
    $scope.updateShipwreck = function() {
        $scope.shipwreck.$update(function(){
            $state.go('shipwrecks');
        });
    };
    $scope.loadShipwreck = function() {
    $scope.shipwreck = Shipwreck.get({id: $stateParams.id})};

    $scope.loadShipwreck();

});
```

Comment: add the HTML code and the js code where you are handling the routing.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Spring Boot before so I'm not sure why it's not loading properly. Are the references for Shipwreck and popupService injected through Spring Boot somehow? If not, you'll need to reference the module(s) that defines them in your module declaration.

With respect to your second question, designing a "cleaner" and more "efficient" codebase requires that you split your "things" into their own files. Basically 1 file per "thing". In this case, 1 file per controller, and 1 file for your module declaration.

The module itself is defined plainly like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'other dependency', 'another', 'etc']);
```

You can add controllers (and other things) to a module you've already defined in another file by using this syntax:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(...);
```

Then you should have a bundling process that combines all relevant files in your module together into 1 file. Typically this will "minify" your js files as well, which requires further tuning of your code to ensure it's "minification safe". Angular's dependency injection format isn't safe by default. Here's an example of a "minification safe" controller:

```
angular
 .module('myApp')
 .controller('controllerName', ['$scope', '$state', 'etc', function($scope, $state, etc){
      //note that the index order of $scope
      //and other dependencies is important 1 matches 1, 2 matches 2, etc.
  }]);
```